# How to evaluate a expression that contains defined functions and return a numeric solution

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, solver

I'm translating a R code to python but i had some error in nsolve function.

I'm trying to evaluate one expression that contain a ifelse statement defined by a function, i Had progress with my code, but I couldn't handle with the dictionary of the variables, i only need a numeric solution, because this a use nsolve function of simpy package, you can see my code below:

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, nsolve
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
import pandas as pd

#Defining ifelse function

def ifelse(cond,yes,no):
   if (cond):
       return(yes)
   else: 
       return (no)  
data = {'A': [10,20,30],
       'B': [20,10,40],
       'FX': ["ifelse(A>B,A-B-x,A+B-x)","ifelse(A+B>20,A+B-x,A*B-x)","ifelse(A<B,A*B-x,A+B-x)"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = Symbol("x", real=True)
cols= df.columns
for row in df.iterrows():
   print(nsolve(parse_expr(row["FX"],local_dict=dict({c:row[c] for c in cols}, **{'x':x}) ),x,0))
```

The code need to return 30,30,1200 as solution, but they present the following error:

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

In the dictionary, I used *for* because the real dataset have hundred of columns and the functions to be solved use many of them.

Someone have idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`row` is a tuple and not a dictionary or pandas data series. In order for the code to work, try using df.iterrows() instead.

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    row["FX"]
```

Edit: Additionally, the function `ifelse` should also be defined in the dictionary since `parse_expr` does not recognize it. So the command should be

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(nsolve(parse_expr(row["FX"], local_dict=dict({c:row[c] for c in cols}, 
                                                       **{'x':x, "ifelse": ifelse})),x,0))
```

Comment: Now I had the following error NameError: name 'ifelse' is not defined, the nsolve is not evaluating my defined function, do you know how to handle this?

Comment: To solve this , the function `ifelse` should also be defined in the dictionary since `parse_expr` does not recognize it. So the command should be

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(nsolve(parse_expr(row["FX"], local_dict=dict({c:row[c] for c in cols}, 
                                                       **{'x':x, "ifelse": ifelse})),x,0))
```. I hope this helps!